# What do you do if you log in to roblox and then it just kicks you out?

Tags: roblox

Since probably 1 month ago I have not been able to get into roblox. I log in and then 1 second later it kicks me out right back to where I started logging in and at this point in time I will pay robux to have this fixed. I have just tried loging in to my account that's it. Does anybody know what has happened if this occures or how to fix it please tell me.

Comment: Can you log into the Roblox website or another place outside the game that uses that account?

Answer (score 3):

That is the kind of thing only Roblox support may fix.

If the game does crash (you are suddenly on your desktop and the game is not on) you might want to uninstall/reinstall the game. Something is corrupted in your install.

I don't know Roblox, but since its an online game we can assume your progression is not saved on your PC. So you will lose nothing.

If the game doesn't crash outright (sends you back to desktop) you might be banned. Then your only option is Roblox support.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Roblox and after that login using the website instead of the app, once you’ve done that reinstall Roblox and see if it works.

:]

Comment: Are you speaking from experience or just making something up that sounds plausible? Not to be rude or anything, but you cite no sources nor indicate _why_ the OP should try this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Roblox, go on to the website and log in. It will tell you if you are banned or not.

This just happened to me, and it was the result of a 7 day ban.

Comment: This sounds like a good response to the answer. I dont play Roblox, but I have a lot of familiarity with the systems employed in what you describe. It sounds odd that you would not be given this feedback (account banned) without deleting the game - are you sure you cant just log in to the website without deleting the game to find out this information? It might be that you followed the other answer, first, so you naturally had the game deleted. *Its bad form to need the player to delete the game before telling them the have been banned*.

Answer (score 0):

I tried logging into my account but I couldn't. After that day, I got into my account. I just had to wait 1 day to get to my account, so maybe that might work for you.